# Leaflet legend: how to setup scroll

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

In leaflet I load a big wms file which also has a legend.
the legend however is very big and doesn't fit the screen.

So I was looking for a way to turn on scrolling in the legend.
However I did not find a method to do so.

I tried overwriting the .legend class in CSS setting a max height and setting the overflow-y to scroll. This does deliver me with a scroll, however scrolling does not work, it would only zoom in and out in the map.

Do you know a way in leaflet to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a page showing the problem or a JSFiddle ?

Comment: well thats kinda hard to. I looked in to it some more, I can alter the CSS, but I think I need to create an extension for the legend so it allows scrolling on the legend.
or at least disables the scrolling of the map if you hover over the legend.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?